# Edit has not improved the answer?

Tags: discussion

This question is being further elaborated from [Question over Neil Meyer's answer](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3193/question-over-neil-meyers-answer) involving Neil Meyer's answer on [Minor key and its chords](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/50040/minor-key-and-its-chords/50042#50042).

Here is how Neil Meyer's answer looked like:

> The chords are...
>
> - Tonic (minor) (A - C - E)
> - Supertonic (diminished) (B - D - F)
> - Mediant (augmented) (C - E - G#)
> - Subdominant (minor) (D - F - A)
> - Dominant (major) (E - G# - B)
> - Submediant (major) (F - A - C)
> - Leading-tone (diminished) (G# - B - D)

Then Tim posted a comment on the answer that looked like this:

> Probably downvoted as not entirely accurate (not by me!). You've not mentioned two other notes which feature in A minor - F# and G. Both of which will allow several other chords to be made diatonically. So there are five more chords that you've missed. And they're triad chords, others are available...

I didn't think Tim's comment was really important to the answer, since the answer already looked good and strongly answered the question.  Neil Meyer's answer was overall great, regardless it had a score of -4.  So on February, I began drinking over 10 liters of the post, and then I peed it out, noticing Neil's use of the "#" sign as a replacement of "♯".  Since "#" and "♯" are two different characters, I believed using "#" as a substitute may have caused confusion to other users, so I made an edit, replacing all "#"s with "♯"s.  My edit was approved, so I knew I was right.  I was feeling all fine until I got a SECOND comment by Tim:

> Maika Sakuranomiya, how has the # sign improved this answer? Which looks already quite unpopular?

I posted my own comment:

> Well, it somehow seemed like if Neil Meyer used # instead of ♯, which may have caused the downvotes, due to proper formatting convention.

THEN Andrew T. typed his / her comment on the answer:

> Maika Sakuranomiya, I don't think one would downvote it just because it used #. Most of us can't even type ♯ without copying from somewhere, and there are many upvoted answers even with #.

---

So, here is the question: **Why didn't the ♯ sign improve the answer, regardless of the fact that it still looked all good?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really believe that there can be confusion between "#" and "♯". Any musician or anyone for that matter can see that they are pretty much the same, and if they don't know/remember the ASCII for "♯", they would most likely just type "#" (me as well). It's faster, easier to remember and quite honestly there isn't much of a difference; not much need to go into all that trouble to find the ASCII code if you don't have the time or you just don't know that there even is such a thing.

I don't think that the answer was downvoted because of these characters. I believe it was poorly written. Just compare it to Richard's answer, where he has 6 paragraphs expanding the answer! In comparison to that, Neil's answer just provided the chords with no explanation whatsoever. Generally on this site we try to help others understand why the answer we post is correct; not just "here is your answer", but "here is your answer and here is why".

Also, concerning the "whether the edit improved the answer", I would have accepted the edit as well most likely, but I don't think it really improved the post. It didn't really change the way people view the post; it didn't really make it easier to comprehend or read.

But don't take it personally. Since you got your edit approved, it was a correct edit. One of the users that accepted that edit is a well-reputed user, who has reviewed many suggested edits. If it was a bad edit, it wouldn't have been accepted or a mod would have rolled back to a previous one.

Answer (score 5):

The use of # over ♯ absolutely was not the cause of downvotes on this answer. If it were, many other good answers would have similar downvotes. But it is silly to think that people are downvoting over this. And there is no world in which changing the characters used for the musical symbols could rescue this answer.

You made this edit almost two months ago; I don't really see why you need to revisit this now. Further, if I was the poster of this downvoted answer, I wouldn't be very happy that you keep calling attention to it by making trivial edits and asking questions linking to it in Meta. But, since you asked:

### "[The] answer was overall great"

The answer got downvotes because it is a low-quality answer. This has been discussed elsewhere, and in particular [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3193/question-over-neil-meyers-answer) in the answers to your earlier question.

### "My edit was approved, so I knew I was right"

I wouldn't say that. Your edit was approved, so two other members of the site let it pass; that doesn't mean that your edit was right. There was I time when I used Unicode musical symbols in all of my answers, and even edited answers in the way that you have, under the assumption that it was an "improvement" to the post. Two things changed my mind about this. A few times someone commented that they couldn't read the symbols on their computer system, i.e. they rendered as blocks or garbage characters. Then this question was asked on Meta: [Do we accept edits that simply update the characters used for accidentals?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/do-we-accept-edits-that-simply-update-the-characters-used-for-accidentals) The consensus on that question was that such edits are not real improvements and should be rejected. When I saw this question and thought about it again, I concluded that such edits are not an improvement, and *possibly detrimental*: detrimental in the sense that these edits can *reduce accessibility for some users.*

As a result, I almost never use the Unicode characters anymore in my answers (and if you make such an edit to one of my posts, I will probably roll it back.) Also, I almost always reject these edits; they just aren't substantive improvements.

### A Prickly Question

Accessibility is a real concern in my opinion; as many users as possible should be able to access the content on Stack Exchange. I don't know how screen-readers handle, say **Bb7** vs **B♭7**. If it turns out the screen-readers can handle the latter but not the former, that might change my mind.